# getDay() method to return day of the week for a given date not works

Tags: java, date, dayofweek, java.util.calendar

I'm trying to complete the task named *Java Date and Time* on HackerRank.

**Task**

> You are given a date. You just need to write the method, getDay, which
>   returns the day on that date.For example, if you are given the date,
>   August 14th 2017, the method should return MONDAY as the day on that
>   date.

I tried my best to do the task but I get either the `null` result or `NullPointerException` error. I wonder where do I do wrong. Below is my code:

Thanks in advance!

**My Code:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String month = in.next();
        String day = in.next();
        String year = in.next();

        System.out.println(getDay(day, month, year));
    }

    public static String getDay(String day, String month, String year) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Integer.valueOf(year), (Integer.valueOf(month) - 1), Integer.valueOf(day));
        return cal.getDisplayName(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK), Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
    }
}
```

Comment: `LocalDate.of( 2017 , 8 , 14 ).getDayOfWeek().toString()` —> MONDAY

Comment: Unless you need it to work on legacy code, you are probably wasting your time learning obsolete APIs...

Comment: @BasilBourque this is Java 8, right?

Comment: @assylias I've just started to do the challenges on HackerRank. I'm a real newbie in programming but I want to be a good competitive programmer eventually. If you have a better advice, I'll be glad to hear it :)

Comment: @SaidBuyukarslan The *java.time* classes are built into Java 8 and later. Much of their functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. Well-worth adding to your project as the legacy classes are an awful mess. Search Stack Overflow for more info. This has been addressed many times already.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `return` is off; you don't want `cal.get` in the first column of `cal.getDisplayName`. Currently, I get the month name with your code. Change that to

```
return cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
```

And call it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getDay("14", "8", "2017"));
}
```

And I get (as expected)

```
Monday
```

In new code, I would *prefer* the new classes in `java.time` (Java 8+), and a `DateTimeFormatter` - like,

```
public static String getDay(String day, String month, String year) {
    int y = Integer.parseInt(year), m = Integer.parseInt(month), d = Integer.parseInt(day);
    return java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE")
            .format(LocalDate.of(y, m, d));
}
```

Comment: It really worked, thank you! Btw, I have two quick questions: 1. After the line `cal.set(Integer.valueOf(year), (Integer.valueOf(month) - 1), Integer.valueOf(day));`, the value of `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` becomes _the actual day of the week_, not the system's current day, right? and 2. using `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` for a string call would be best if I just want to have the int value of the day alone. like: `int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);` (which returns something between 1-7).

Comment: One: [`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) is a `static final` constant [`7`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK). It does not "become *the actual day of the week*", it never changes. It's a constant. Two: Look at [`Calendar.SUNDAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#SUNDAY) it's a [`1`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.SUNDAY). Three: Prefer classes in `java.time` over `java.util.Calendar`

Comment: Alternatively, instead of calling `.format` you can call `.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName` to automatically localize the name of the day-of-week.

Answer (score 3):

## `java.time.LocalDate`

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

1. Import [`java.time.*`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) to access [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) & [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) classes.
2. Write `getDay` method which should be static because it is called in main method.
3. Retrieve localDate by using `of` method which takes 3 arguments in "int" format.
4. convert the `getDay` method arguments in int format.
5. finally retrieve name of that day using `getDayOfWeek` method.

There is one video on this challenge.
[Java Date and Time Hackerrank](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eiN_1P0Hk8&lc=Ugxd6MOR80mcO7XjU_R4AaABAg)

```
LocalDate                 // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 )      // Pass year-month-day, 1-12 for January-December. 
.getDayOfWeek()           // Obtain a `DayOfWeek` enum object.
.getDisplayName(          // Automatically localize the name of the day-of-week.
    TextStyle.FULL ,      // How long or abbreviated.
    Locale.US             // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH or so on.
)                         // Returns `String` such as `Monday` or `lundi`.
```

For Java 6 & 7, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTenABP* project.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use LocalDate, you can use it this way

```
 import java.time.LocalDate;

 public static String getDay(int month, int day, int year) {

    return LocalDate.of(year, month, day).getDayOfWeek().name();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. It’s certainly a good suggestion, I think it’s already in a number of the other answers (with very slight variations).

Answer (score 1):

Formatting data and time using java.util date and calendar as follows, where it needed to handle an exception with java.text.SimpleDateFormat in java 7.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String inputDateStr = String.format("%s/%s/%s", 23, 04, 1995);
    Date inputDate = null;
    try {
        inputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(inputDateStr);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication28.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(inputDate);
    String dayOfWeek = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US).toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(dayOfWeek);

}
```

Formatting date and time using java.time classes in java 8 as follows and it is immutable and thread-safe.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime; 
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter; 

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime dateObj = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println("Before formatting: " + dateObj);
    DateTimeFormatter formatObj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    String formattedDate = dateObj.format(formatObj);
    System.out.println("After formatting: " + formattedDate);
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static String getDay(int month, int day, int year) {
   String  res= java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE")
        .format(java.time.LocalDate.of(year, month, day));
   return res;    }
```

must use java.time.LocalDate, if u will use direct LocalDate its show compile time error i.e cannot find symbol, so plz use java.time.

Comment: You may add importstatements `import java.time.LocalDate;` and `import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;`, then you don’t need the qualifications `java.time` and `java.time.format` in the method.

Comment: Ya , you can also do that

Answer (score 1):

You can use new Java8 DateTime API.

```
public static String getDay(int day, int month, int year) 
{
    LocalDate dt=LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
    System.out.println("day: " + dt.getDayOfWeek().toString());
    return dt.getDayOfWeek().toString();
}
```

A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day, so fine for our purpose. The `of` factory method constructs the date that we want. Contrary to the `Calendar` class used in the question it numbers the months sanely from 1 for January through 12 for December. A `LocalDate` has a getter for day of week. It returns a constant from the `DayOfWeek` enum whose `toString` method gives us a nice readable string such as `MONDAY`, again in contrast to what we get from `Calendar`.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String findDay(int month, int day, int year) {
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, (month - 1), day);
    String dayOfWeek = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
    return dayOfWeek.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DayOfWeek`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String findDay(int month, int day, int year) {
     Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        rightNow.set(year, month-1, day);;
        switch(rightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
            case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                return "SUNDAY";
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                return "MONDAY";
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                return "TUEDAY";
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                return "WEDNESDAY";
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                return "THURSDAY";
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                return "FRIDAY";
            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                return "SATURDAY";            
   
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. This is a poor answer in some respects. As many have pointed out already, no one should use the cumbersome and outdated `Calendar` class anymore. The code is too manual, too handheld. Compare to the simpler and shorter code in each and every other answer. And code-only answers are not very useful. It’s from the explanations that we all learn. So in your next answers, please provide some.